# What does this mean? '誰もがここで生まれたので、学校は大変でした.'

Tags: grammar, kanji

I have been trying to translate 'school was hard because everyone was born here (australia)' and am not sure if this is the right grammar or not.

Comment: I have trouble even understanding the meaning in English. Why was everyone born "here" (in Australia)? (I wasn't born there.) And what does that have to do with school being hard? Is school easier in places where nobody is born...?

Comment: i mean that everyone in my class was born in australia when i first came to school, and i was not.

Comment: I think you would be better off using the Japanese for  "I was not born here", for the first half of your sentence. It more naturally gets your point across, instead of trying to say "everyone else was born here"... and it should be less confusing to write.

Comment: @Timothy A question I asked which is related to yours: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/61118/how-to-say-everyone-but-me

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically speaking, this is a fairly simple sentence, and your understanding of the sentence is basically OK. But it's a little difficult to make sense of it without proper context. When you ask about the interpretation of a sentence, please don't forget to include some context. Usually a few surrounding sentences will greatly help.

誰もがここで生まれたので just means "because everyone was bone here". What 誰も actually refers to depends on the context. It may be "everyone in my village", "everyone in my class", etc.

学校は大変でした is technically ambiguous, and many sentences are ambiguous without proper context in topic-prominent languages like Japanese. Roughly speaking, this sentence can mean:

1. the school had hard time (because of these people)
2. these people (may or may not include the speaker) had a hard time about something related to school
3. I had hard time at school

From the context you provided, I think the sentence means "Everyone **in my class but me** was born here **in Australia**, so I had hard time at school (due to language problems, etc)".